# css image overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive-slides

I'm having an issue with with [**ResponsiveSlides.js**](http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/).
On [**my site**](http://thecharlesnyc.com/dev/dgi/ExpressionEngine/index.php#.UQgf6nD9suf) I'm having an overflow issue with the slider in the clients section.

When the slide changes you'll notice the images overlap the red block in the client section. I believe I have added the correct properties in my CSS.

Below is a CSS snippet:

```
.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.rslides1 li {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

The CSS above is the default CSS for the slider. Below are elements I have added to suit my site:

```
.clinet-slide-img {
    width: 100%;
}
.left-side {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Looks ok to me.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović if you scroll to the client section you'll notice when the slide changes the images overlaps the red block

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: looks fine on chrome/mac

Comment: Looks fine on firefox/windows

Comment: Yup that's bcos i have fixed the issue

Comment: hi the link going to your site give me this error `Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found`